# I deployed the launchpad contract, but the result is 0x00000. What could be the cause?

Tags: solidity

**Deployer**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./launchpad.sol";

contract Deployer is Ownable {
    uint256 public launchpadCount;
    uint256 public deployCost = 0.01 ether;
    uint256 public totalInvested;
    uint256 public totalParticipants;
    uint256 public ownerFee;

    address public senseiLocker;

    mapping(uint256 => address) public launchpadById;
    mapping(address => uint256) public launchpadIdByAddress;
    mapping(address => bool) private isLaunchpad;
    mapping(address => address) public launchpadByToken;
    mapping(address => address[]) public userLaunchpadInvested;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) isLaunchpadAdded;

    event launchpadDeployed(address newTokenAddress, address deployer);

    constructor() {
        // Constructor logic can be added here, if needed.
    }

    function createLaunchpad(
        uint256[] memory _prices,
        uint256[] memory _caps,
        uint256[] memory _limits,
        uint256[] memory _times,
        uint256 _lockupPeriod,
        uint256 _liquidityPerc,
        string memory _URIData,
        address _token,
        bool whitelist
    ) public payable {
        require(msg.value >= deployCost, "Not enough BNB to deploy");
        require(launchpadByToken[_token] == address(0), "Launchpad already created");

        address[] memory _addresses = new address[](3);
        _addresses[0] = _token;
        _addresses[1] = msg.sender;
        _addresses[2] = senseiLocker;

        launchPad newLaunchpad = new launchPad(
            _prices,
            _caps,
            _times,
            _URIData,
            ownerFee,
            _token,
            owner(),
            address(this),
            whitelist  // Pass 'whitelist' argument here
        );
        newLaunchpad.transferOwnership(owner());

        uint256 tokensToDistribute = _prices[0] * _caps[1];
        uint256 tokensToLiquidity = (_prices[1] * _caps[1] * _liquidityPerc) / 100;
        uint256 tokensNeeded = ((tokensToDistribute + tokensToLiquidity) * 10**ERC20(_token).decimals()) / 100000000;

        ERC20(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(newLaunchpad), tokensNeeded);

        payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);

        launchpadById[launchpadCount] = address(newLaunchpad);
        launchpadIdByAddress[address(newLaunchpad)] = launchpadCount;
        launchpadCount++;

        launchpadByToken[_token] = address(newLaunchpad);
        isLaunchpad[address(newLaunchpad)] = true;

        emit launchpadDeployed(address(newLaunchpad), msg.sender);
    }

    function getDeployedLaunchpads(uint256 startIndex, uint256 endIndex)
        public
        view
        returns (address[] memory)
    {
        if (endIndex >= launchpadCount) {
            endIndex = launchpadCount - 1;
        }

        uint256 arrayLength = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
        uint256 currentIndex;
        address[] memory launchpadAddress = new address[](arrayLength);

        for (uint256 i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
            launchpadAddress[currentIndex] = launchpadById[startIndex + i];
            currentIndex++;
        }

        return launchpadAddress;
    }

    function setPrice(uint256 _price) external onlyOwner {
        deployCost = _price;
    }

    function getInfo(uint256 id)
        external
        view
        returns (
            uint256[] memory data,
            uint8 _status,
            uint8 decimals,
            uint256 _score,
            string memory _URIData,
            string[] memory symbol,
            address _contractAdmin,
            address _tokenAddress,
            address contractAddress,
            bool[] memory booleans
        )
    {
        contractAddress = launchpadById[id];

        launchPad instance = launchPad(contractAddress);

        data = instance.getContractNumbers();

        (
        uint8 _status,
        uint256[] memory numbers,
        string memory _URIData,
        address _contractAdmin,
        address _tokenAddress,
        bool _kyc
    ) = instance.getContractInfo();


        symbol = new string[](2);

        decimals = ERC20(_tokenAddress).decimals();
        symbol[0] = ERC20(_tokenAddress).symbol();
        symbol[1] = ERC20(_tokenAddress).name();
    }

    function addToUserLaunchpad(address _user, address _launchpad) external {
        require(isLaunchpad[msg.sender], "Only launchpads can add");

        if (!isLaunchpadAdded[_user][_launchpad]) {
            userLaunchpadInvested[_user].push(_launchpad);
            isLaunchpadAdded[_user][_launchpad] = true;
        }
    }

    function updateStats(uint256 _invested, uint256 _contributors) external {
        require(isLaunchpad[msg.sender], "Only launchpads can add");

        totalInvested += _invested;
        totalParticipants += _contributors;
    }

    function removeLaunchpad(address _token, address _launchpad) external {
        require(isLaunchpad[msg.sender], "Only launchpads can remove");

        launchpadByToken[_token] = address(0);
        isLaunchpad[_launchpad] = false;
    }

    function getUserContributions(address _user)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory contributions)
    {
        uint256 count = userLaunchpadInvested[_user].length;
        ids = new uint256[](count);
        contributions = new uint256[](count);

        for (uint256 i; i < count; i++) {
            address launchpadaddress = userLaunchpadInvested[_user][i];
            ids[i] = launchpadIdByAddress[launchpadaddress];
            contributions[i] = launchPad(launchpadaddress).depositedAmount(
                _user
            );
        }
    }

    function getStats()
        external
        view
        returns (
            uint256 _projects,
            uint256 _invested,
            uint256 _participants
        )
    {
        _projects = launchpadCount;
        _invested = totalInvested;
        _participants = totalParticipants;
    }

    function changeLockerAddress(address _newLocker) external onlyOwner {
        senseiLocker = _newLocker;
    }
}
```

**launchpad code**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

import "./IDeployer.sol";

contract launchPad is Ownable, Pausable {
    uint256 public softCap;
    uint256 public hardCap;
    uint256 public startTime;
    uint256 public endTime;
    uint256 public totalDeposits;
    uint256 public contributors;
    uint256 public ownerFee;
    uint8 public status; // 0- open, 1- finish, 2- refund

    string public URIData;

    address public tokenToReceive;
    address public contractAdmin;

    bool public kyc;

    mapping (address => uint256) public depositedAmount;
    mapping (uint256 => address) public contributorsList;

    IDeployer deployer;

    event userDeposit(uint256 amount, address user);
    event userRefunded(uint256 amount, address user);
    event saleClosed(uint256 timeStamp, uint256 collectedAmount);
    event saleCanceled(uint256 timeStamp, address operator);

    constructor(
    uint256[] memory _prices,
        uint256[] memory _caps,
        uint256[] memory _times,
        string memory _URIData,
        uint256 _fee,
        address _tokenToReceive,
        address _contractAdmin,
        address _deployer,
        bool whitelist
    ) {
        // Inisialisasi kontrak dengan parameter yang sesuai
        softCap = (_caps[0] * 10**18) / 10000;
        hardCap = (_caps[1] * 10**18) / 10000;
        startTime = _times[0];
        endTime = _times[1];
        URIData = _URIData;
        ownerFee = _fee;
        tokenToReceive = _tokenToReceive;
        contractAdmin = _contractAdmin;
        deployer = IDeployer(_deployer);
    }

    modifier restricted(){
        require(msg.sender == owner() || msg.sender == contractAdmin, "Caller not allowed");
        _;
    }

    function invest(uint256 _amount) external payable {
        require(status == 0, "Sale is not open");
        require(startTime < block.timestamp, "Sale is not open yet");
        require(endTime > block.timestamp, "Sale is already closed");
        require(_amount + totalDeposits <= hardCap, "Hardcap reached");

        if (tokenToReceive == address(0)) {
            require(_amount == msg.value, "Invalid payment amount");
        } else {
            // Transfer tokens to the contract
            IERC20(tokenToReceive).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
        }

        if (depositedAmount[msg.sender] == 0) {
            contributorsList[contributors] = msg.sender;
            contributors++;
        }

        depositedAmount[msg.sender] = depositedAmount[msg.sender] + _amount;
        totalDeposits += _amount;

        deployer.addToUserLaunchpad(msg.sender, address(this));

        emit userDeposit(_amount, msg.sender);
    }

    function claimRefund () external {
        require(status == 2, "Refund is not available");
        uint256 deposit = depositedAmount[msg.sender];
        require(deposit > 0, "User doesn't have deposits");

        depositedAmount[msg.sender] = 0;

        if(tokenToReceive == address(0)){
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(deposit);
        } else {
            IERC20(tokenToReceive).transfer(msg.sender, deposit);
        }

        emit userRefunded(deposit, msg.sender);
    }

    function finishSale () external restricted {
        require(block.timestamp > endTime || totalDeposits == hardCap, "Sales has not ended yet");
        require(status == 0, "Sale is already finished");
        require(totalDeposits >= softCap, "Soft cap not reached");

        status = 1;

        deployer.updateStats(totalDeposits, contributors);

        withdraw();

        emit saleClosed(block.timestamp, totalDeposits);
    }

    function cancelSale () external restricted {
        require(status == 0, "Sale is already finished");

        status = 2;

        deployer.removeLaunchpad(address(this));

        emit saleCanceled(block.timestamp, msg.sender);
    }

    function withdraw () internal {
        uint256 balance;
        uint256 fee;

        if(ownerFee > 0){
            fee = (totalDeposits * ownerFee) / 10000;
        }

        if(tokenToReceive == address(0)){
            balance = address(this).balance;
            payable(owner()).transfer(fee);
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(balance - fee);
        } else {
            balance = IERC20(tokenToReceive).balanceOf(address(this));
            IERC20(tokenToReceive).transfer(owner(), balance - fee);
            IERC20(tokenToReceive).transfer(msg.sender, balance);
        }
    }

    function getContractNumbers() public view returns (uint256 [] memory data){
        data = new uint256[](6);
        data[0] = softCap;
        data[1] = hardCap;
        data[2] = startTime;
        data[3] = endTime;
        data[4] = totalDeposits;
        data[5] = contributors;
    }

    function getContractInfo() external view returns (uint8 _status, uint256 [] memory numbers, string memory _URIData, address _contractAdmin, address _tokenAddress, bool _kyc){
        _status = status;
        numbers = getContractNumbers();
        _URIData = URIData;
        _contractAdmin = contractAdmin;
        _tokenAddress = tokenToReceive;
        _kyc = kyc;
    }

    function getContributorsList() external view returns (address [] memory list, uint256 [] memory amounts){
        list = new address [](contributors);
        amounts = new uint256 [](contributors);

        for (uint256 i; i < contributors; i++) {
            address userAddress = contributorsList[i];
            list[i] = userAddress;
            amounts[i] = depositedAmount[userAddress];
        }
    }

    function changeData(string memory _newData) external onlyOwner {
        URIData = _newData;
    }
}
```

**Test code**

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');

describe('Deployer', function () {
  it('should create a new launchPad contract', async function () {

    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://rpc.testnet.mantle.xyz');const wallet = new ethers.Wallet('8c80b48c50cf9cf1229e2bcb0ab148c40bdbdfd9e458691ffaa8831d7b4d6f2f', provider);
    // Deploy the Deployer contract
    const Deployer = await ethers.getContractFactory('Deployer');
    const deployer = await Deployer.deploy();

    // Set the desired deployCost (0.01 BNB in Wei)
    const deployCost = ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.01", "ether");

    // Wait for the deployment to complete
    await deployer.deployed();

    // Set the deployCost for the Deployer contract
    await deployer.setPrice(deployCost);

    // Parameter untuk fungsi createLaunchpad
    const prices = [100, 200]; // Harga penawaran dan harga penawaran listing
    const caps = [1000, 2000]; // Soft cap dan hard cap
    const limits = [1, 10]; // Pembelian minimum dan maksimum
    const times = [1679824000, 1679838000]; // Waktu mulai dan waktu berakhir (gantilah dengan waktu yang sesuai)
    const lockupPeriod = 30; // Periode lockup dalam hari
    const liquidityPerc = 50; // Persentase likuiditas
    const URIData = 'https://example.com/ipfsdata'; // URL data URI
    const token = '0x8a356fB37ebCF9765B5032Bc6C000CCdF976A665'; // Replace with a valid token address
    const whitelist = false; // Aktifkan atau nonaktifkan whitelist sesuai kebutuhan

    // Call createLaunchpad
    await deployer.createLaunchpad(prices, caps, limits, times, lockupPeriod, liquidityPerc, URIData, token, whitelist, {
      gasLimit: 3000000,
    });

    // Get the address of the newly created launchPad contract
    const launchpadAddress = await deployer.launchpadByToken(token);

    // Check if the launchPad contract exists
    expect(launchpadAddress).to.not.equal(ethers.constants.AddressZero);

    // Add approval step before transferFrom
    await ERC20(token).approve(launchpadAddress, tokensNeeded);


    // You can also log the transaction details for more information
    console.log("Transaction Hash:", transaction.hash);
    console.log("Gas Used:", (await transaction.wait()).gasUsed.toString());
  });
});
```

**console**
Deployer
1) should create a new launchPad contract

0 passing (11s)
1 failing

1. Deployer
   should create a new launchPad contract:

   AssertionError: expected '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000…' to not equal '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000…'

   - expected - actual

   at Context. (test\test.js:42:37)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: It is likely that `createLaunchpad` failed. Check if the gas limit is enough.

Comment: Thanks very much